# Is there any way to display ER diagram on my website?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a lot of databases, and I have exported the schemas (including table name, PK, FK, etc) from my databases and formatted them in Json format. I want to display the ER diagrams on my my website, any suggestion?

I found there are many online tools to create ER diagrams, but no tools can display ER Diagrams web site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Oracle SQL Developer that allows to create ER diagrams and export them to HTML/SVG, PDF, PNG.

At the Oracle SQL Developer you can click the [File]->[Data Modeler]->[Import] and choose from a variety of formats including DDL, SQL, XML, Data Dictionaries etc. You can read the documentation of the Oracle's SQL Developer about the reporting and modeling functionality provided.